# How to make wget download recursive combining --accept with --exclude-directories?

Tags: wget, http

I'm trying to download some directories from an Apache server, but I need to ignore some directories that have huge files I don't care about

The dir structure in the server is somewhat like this (simplified):

```
somedir/
├── atxt.txt
├── big_file.pdf
├── image.jpg
└── tmp
    └── tempfile.txt
```

So, I want to get all the `.txt` and `.jpg` files, but I DON'T want the `.pdf` files nor anything that is in a `tmp` directory.

I've tried using `--exclude-directories` together with `--accept` and then with `--reject`, but in both attempts it keeps downloading the `tmp` dir and its contents.

These are the commands I've tried:

```
# with --reject
wget -nH --cut-dirs=2 -r --reject=pdf --exclude-directories=tmp \
         --no-parent  http://<host>/pub/somedir/

# with --accept
wget -nH --cut-dirs=2 -r --accept=txt,jpg --exclude-directories=tmp \
         --no-parent  http://<host>/pub/somedir/
```

Is there a way to do this?

How exactly is `--exclude-directories` supposed to work?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than try and do this using `wget` I'd suggest using a more appropriate tool for downloading complex "sets" of files or filters.

You can use [`httrack`](http://www.httrack.com/) to download either entire directories of files (essentially mirror everything from a site) or you can specify to `httrack` a filter along with specific file extensions, such as download only `.pdf` files.

You can read more about [`httrack`'s filter capability](http://www.httrack.com/html/filters.html) which is what you'd need to use if you were interested in only downloading files that were named in a specific way.

Here are some examples of the wildcard capability:

- `*[file]` or `*[name]` - any filename or name, e.g. not /,? and ; characters
- `*[path]`              - any path (and filename), e.g. not ? and ; characters
- `*[a,z,e,r,t,y]`       - any letters among a,z,e,r,t,y
- `*[a-z]` - any letters
- `*[0-9,a,z,e,r,t,y]` - any characters among 0..9 and a,z,e,r,t,y

#### Example

```
$ httrack http://url.com/files/ -* +1_[a-z].doc -O /dir/to/output
```

The switches are as follows:

- `-*` - remove everything from list of things to download
- `+1_[a-z].doc` - download files named 1_a.doc, 1_b.doc, etc.
- `-O /dir/to/output` - write results here

Comment: httrack is definitely a better way.

Comment: `httrack -W` always recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going to give httrack a try. I really wish to know how the `--exclude-directories` option works, though. It's ignored even without combining `--accept` or `--reject`.

Comment: @elias - in the man page it says it takes wildcards, so perhaps you need to define the "directories" using something like `*/tmp/*`.

Comment: httrack does not support custom headers (needed for authentication).  Wget does.

Comment: There is also cURL, (http://curl.haxx.se) which is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case where I did the equivalent of what would be for you `--exclude-directories '/tmp'` and it worked for me.

See also https://serverfault.com/questions/156045/how-to-download-with-wget-without-following-links-with-parameters/156057#156057 for more powerful options on recent wget (regular expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Many including me had problems figuring out how to use -X, and found the answer hard to remember (between years of span between use).

This is a hard to remember trick write it down :)

```
$ wget -X fo*o ... # does not work for directories
$ wget -X */fo*o,*/*/fo*o,*/*/*/fo*o ... # works for directories
$ wget -X \*/fo\*o/,\*/\*/fo\*o/,\*/\*/\*/fo\*o/ ...
```

*ANSWER:*

site hack wget-?/src/utils.c so to use basename instead of current path, also on command line use filename pattern (just 'fo*o', nothing else).  and note param FNM_PATHNAME set to 0 (otherwise it demands '/' to finish tail of match).  the following patch is against wget-1.12  there my be a simpler way by definining ?FNM_FLAGS but this works "fine".

```
--- utils.c.old 2016-09-13 07:49:11.000000000 -0400
+++ utils.c 2016-09-13 09:32:58.000000000 -0400
@@ -907,6 +907,9 @@
   return *d1 == '\0' && (*d2 == '\0' || *d2 == '/');
 }

+/* for basename */
+#include <libgen.h>
+
 /* Iterate through DIRLIST (which must be NULL-terminated), and return the
    first element that matches DIR, through wildcards or front comparison (as
    appropriate).  */
@@ -921,18 +924,24 @@
     {
       /* Remove leading '/' */
       char *p = *x + (**x == '/');
+      /* SITE HACK - only if patterned ignore leading dirs cmp as file */
+      char sh_str[1024*16], *pp;
+      strcpy(sh_str,basename(dir));
+      pp=sh_str;
+#if 0
+      printf("? %s == %s ?\n",p,pp); 
+#endif
       if (has_wildcards_p (p))
         {
-          if (matcher (p, dir, FNM_PATHNAME) == 0)
+          if (matcher (p, pp, 0) == 0)
             break;
         }
       else
         {
-          if (subdir_p (p, dir))
+          if (subdir_p (p, pp))
             break;
         }
     }
-
   return *x ? true : false;
 }
```